# How to get UUID in php created from trigger in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, uuid, database-trigger, last-insert-id

I have a table in mysql which uses a trigger to create a uuid on insert. My question is how can i get that via php after the insert and trigger was completed.

Comment: @ObsidianAge all the answers in that question are awful though. I'd personally suggest not generating the UUID in MySQL at all, but rather in the application beforehand.

Comment: Alternatively, use whatever else in the row data that uniquely identifies to select the row after insert. While UUIDs are great as immutable, non-sequential surrogate keys you should still have some other columns that uniquely identify the row even though they might be mutable.